# How do I resize a folded box without messing up the folds on the top or stretching out the squares (thus messing up mapping)?

Tags: modeling, uv, scale

I'm using a classic folded box that has already been created by someone else.
I want to increase the height, but when I scale along the y axis, the folds on the top get stretched too much.

How do I just stretch the bottom of the box in height and leave the folds alone?

Edited for new issue: When I drag and stretch, all those little squares get messed up and then when I map a graphic onto it, it looks all stretched in that area.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways, a simple one is:

- go in edit mode (tab)
- select all edges in the base of the cube (xray mode can help you to select all the base)
- G (to move the selection), Z (to block the movement only in the Z axis), move mouse to decide how far to move the base of the cube

[image]

**HOW TO FIX THE UV:**

1. fix the geometry in edit mode --> the texture is now stretched

[image]

1. go into UV editor, select the faces with stretched texture, go into UV editor, select the base nodes (the one that you moved to change the size of the box) and move them into the UV editor to fix the textures:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My new issue (which I've edited my post to reflect) is that the box was made with many squares and when I drag half of them down, there's a big swatch of space. When I add a graphic later (which I'm doing in Adobe Dimension because I'm not so fluent in Blender yet) the graphic is wrongly stretched across that area. How can I prevent that?

Comment: edited my answer with some basic info about the UV fix

Answer (score 3):

If this model has no UV map Or you don't mind messing the UVs then just go to Edit mode and 
box select the bottom half of the object and move it downward.

[image]

Comment: Ohhhh okay what you're doing is just grabbing and dragging? Ok until this I thought I could only expand something using scale but this makes sense! Thanks. (PS How do I do this grab-and-drag method while ensuring that it's locked to stay straight? I don't want to accidently skew my box a degree left or right...)

Comment: When you are dragging press X, Y or Z to lock the dragging/grabbing along its selected global axis. Press XX, YY or ZZ to lock it along its selected local axis

Comment: Thank you! My new issue (which I've edited my post to reflect) is that the box was made with many squares and when I drag half of them down, there's a big swatch of space. When I add a graphic later (which I'm doing in Adobe Dimension because I'm not so fluent in Blender yet) the graphic is wrongly stretched across that area. How can I prevent that?

Comment: You can easily fix these squares by resizing the UV map of the object... 
Are you willing to look for a tutorial about the UV maps in Blender ? :)

Comment: I totally don't understand what that means but I will definitely look for a tutorial, haha. Blender really hurts my head but I'm trying to learn bit by bit! If you know of any clear tutorials about UV maps please send them my way :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM&feature=emb_logo Understand UV here :) Good Luck